# PHP if referrer is not .... - show error?

Tags: php

I have a script, and I want to basically do the following:

```
http://www.site.com/interstitial/HASH
```

For example:

```
http://www.site.com/interstitial/66274bc2836508057cd0335831c16e93
```

I basically want to do that if the person is not directed to x.php from the given link above, it shows an error.

So, if page is not visited from referrer then spew out an error?

Answer (score 8):

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] != '...') {
   die('error');
}
```

But keep in mind that the referrer is easily spoofed. Better set session variable at x.php, and check for its existence at the other page.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` may not be set. So I recommend you add an `isset` or `array_key_exists` check. And use `!==` since similar strings are actually equal in PHP.